# SocketIo integration with Django

Tags: python, node.js, django, socket.io

I have been trying to integrate socketio with Django, And I am getting the following error.

```
[31/Mar/2020 14:50:27] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4n4ds4&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 117
[31/Mar/2020 14:50:27] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N4n4dsj&b64=1&sid=9053be92266c46148304c09833b2ebe8 HTTP/1.1" 200 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 558, in handle_request
    return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 377, in handle_request
    environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 108, in handle_get_request
    start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 152, in _upgrade_websocket
    return ws(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/async_drivers/eventlet.py", line 16, in __call__
    raise RuntimeError('You need to use the eventlet server. '
RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.
[31/Mar/2020 14:50:27] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=9053be92266c46148304c09833b2ebe8 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52220)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/murali/yourenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

The link I was referring https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/django-websocket-with-socketio

**Below is my code:**

requirements.txt:

```
enum-compat==0.0.2
eventlet==0.25.1
python-engineio
python-socketio
pytz==2018.7
six==1.10.0
```

settings.py: added socketio in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'socketio'
]
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import eventlet
import socketio
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'integrate_socketio.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
sio = socketio.Server()
application = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, application)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.hello, name='hello')
]
```

view.py

```
import eventlet
async_mode = eventlet
import os
from django.http import HttpResponse
import socketio

basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='eventlet')\

@sio.on('connection-bind')
def connection_bind(sid, data):
    print("sid:",sid,"data",data)

@sio.on('message')
def message(data):
    print(data)
    sio.emit('test',data)
@sio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect(sid):
    print("Disconnected")
def hello(data):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Below is the code for client written in nodejs,

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000', {reconnect: false});

socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
socket.emit('message', 'messgae', 'test msg');
socket.on('test', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

To run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get response when I open http://localhost:8000/ in the browser, but above error comes when I run  nodejs client.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 5):

## Problem

The problem is the `async_mode` parameter for the `socketio.Server` instance (the `sio`). The parameter basically chooses what model to use when running. Each model type needs to be run in a certain way. The default for `async_mode` is `'eventlet'`, which means that the SocketIO server needs to be run with eventlet. In your case, it seems that it has defaulted to `'eventlet'`, but you aren't running your django server with eventlet, which is raising an error. To fix this, you can either change the `sio` parameters to be compatible with your way of (solution 1) or you can configure your wsgi.py to run the server with eventlet (solution 2).

---

## Solution 1

You can change the `sio` parameters on initialization as follows:

```py
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='mode') # Change 'mode' to your mode
```

You can change `'mode'` based on how you are running your server. The options are `'gevent_uwsgi'`, `'gevent'`, or `'threading'` (or `'eventlet'`, `None`, but neither would solve your problem).

By the looks of your run statement, you aren't using gunicorn or uwsgi, so in your case, it would be best if you used `threading` or `gevent`. (The instructions for using gunicorn or uwsgi with `'gevent'` or `'gevent_uwsgi'` respectively are in the official docs cited at the bottom)

If you are using `'threading'`, you don't need to install anything or change anything in your wsgi.py (other than the mode), but it *is* comparatively slower in terms of performance.

If you are using `'gevent'`, you would need to install gevent as follows:

```sh
$ pip install gevent
```

Then, you would need to change some settings in wsgi.py. If you have the gevent websocket transport installed then add the following to the bottom of your wsgi.py:

```py
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 8000), app, 
    handler_class=WebSocketHandler).serve_forever()
```

If not, then add the following instead:

```py
from gevent import pywsgi
pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 8000), app).serve_forever()
```

---

## Solution 2

If you decide to configure your wsgi.py to run with eventlet, you first install eventlet...

```sh
$ pip install eventlet
```

...and add the following to the bottom of your wsgi.py:

```py
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

---

#### Citation

I got all the info from [this website](https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-use-python-socket-io-with-django#Edit%20WSGI%20File%20for%20Python%20SocketIO) and the [official socket.io documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#deployment-strategies). The official documentation also has instructions for using the other modes from "solution 1"